# Recursive Factorial Function Loop

Tags: r

I don't have any data but I need to create a recurive functions that loops the variable x between 1 and 10.  I need to do a factorial function so the factorial of 5 is 5*4*3*2*1.

This is for a class.  The problem I was given is Factorial(x) = x*Factorial(x-1)

I was trying to write something like the following but it isn't working.  Any thoughts?

```
factorial <- function(x){
y <- 1
for(i in 1:10){
y <-y*((1:x)[i])
print(y)
}
}
```

Comment: `x*(1:x)` produces a vector of `1, 2, ..., x`. You need to multiply this. Try `prod`. I'm not sure you need that `[i]`.

Comment: Since this is homework, you really ought to work it out yourself.